# Nested ng-repeat with different data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJS v1.5.0 in my web application. I have feedbacks of the users which are displayed using ng-repeat. Now whenever the executive clicks on the feedback, I make a server call and fetch the history of user and show it on the panel.

Once the call is successful, I assign the data to the `feebackDetails` variable which is now the controller scope variable. But I dont want it to have the controller scope, as each feedback will have different user and different data.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in" ng-controller="controller-feedback" id="feedback">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="feedback in feedbacks track by $index" ng-click="getUserHistory(feedback.userId)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#feedback{{$index}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#feedback{{$index}}">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <div>{{feedback.feedback}}</div>
                    <div class="collapse" id="feedback{{$index}}">
                        <div class="well">
                            <div ng-repeat="feedbackDetail in feedbackDetails track by $index">
                                <span style="font-weight: bold">Question:</span> {{feedbackDetail.question}} <br>
                                <span style="font-weight: bold">Answer:</span> {{feedbackDetail.answer}} <br>
                                <span style="font-weight: bold">Helpful:</span> {{feedbackDetail.helpful}} <br>
                                <span style="font-weight: bold">Feedback:</span> {{feedbackDetail.feedback}} <br>
                                <span style="font-weight: bold">Executive:</span> {{feedbackDetail.executive}} <br>
                                <hr ng-hide="$last">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller part.

```
app.controller('controller-feedback', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    $scope.feedbacks = [];
    $scope.feedbackDetails = [];

    // This will get the feedbacks
    $http
        .get(phpUrl + 'test-feedback', {params:{doctorId:doctorId}})
        .then(function success(response) {
            $scope.feedbacks = response.data.data;
            $rootScope.feedbackCount = response.data.data.length.toString();
        }, function error(success) {

        });

    $scope.getUserHistory = function(userId) {
        console.log(userId);

        $http
            .get(phpUrl + 'test-feedback-details', {params:{userId:userId}})
            .then(function success(response) {

                /**
                 * This variable $scope.feedbackDetails must be different for each ng-repeat
                 */
                $scope.feedbackDetails = response.data;
            }, function error(success) {

            });
    };
});
```

[image: Current output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `getUserHistory` to accept `feedback` object.

```
$scope.getUserHistory = function(feedback) {
var userId = feedback. userId ....
```

and rather than

```
$scope.feedbackDetails = response.data;
```

assign

```
$scope.feedback.feedbackDetails = response.data;
```

Inner ng-repeat should use feedback.feedbackDetails.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive called `feedbackDetail` that you put inside your `ng-repeat` which uses an isolate-scope and you pass in your `feedbackDetail` from the `ng-repeat`.
Then when you make the HTTP request from the directives controller and assign it to `$scope` it would be a scope for just that part of the repeat.